# Django convert imagefield to Foreign key UUID

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have django project in that, i had imagefield like below

`certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1000)`

but i need to change the imagefield to foreign key UUID, like below

`certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificates, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

but i'm getting migrate error like below,

```
Applying templates.0016_auto_20200502_0452...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sakthips/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""
```

this error is little weird, can someone help me to resolve. I know i can **delete the existing field and add new field** that's one solution. I was expecting some other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the certificate imagefield was changed, it maybe has data of column certificate. So django want to modify the data to a new type, sometimes some datas can not be casted, then error rised.

### two methods to solve it:

1. open the database, drop the column concerned of the target table.
2. comment certificate column in feature model and form concerned, then makemigrations and migrate to drop certificate column. Uncomment certificate(ForeignKey) column and form concerned, then redo makemigrations and migrate to add new certificate_id column.

Hope it is helpful to you.